# Add column in dataframe based on 3 columns from another dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, purrr

I have 2 dataframes which are as follows:

**Dataframe 1:** *traffic_df* which is hourly data.

| Date_Time | Traffic |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-09 06:00:00 | 10 |
| 2020-03-09 07:00:00 | 20 |
| 2020-03-10 07:00:00 | 20 |
| 2020-03-24 08:00:00 | 15 |

**Dataframe 2:** *Alert.level*

| Start | End | Alert.level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/03/2020 13:30 | 23/03/2020 13:30 | 2 |
| 23/03/2020 13:30 | 25/03/2020 23:59 | 3 |

I want to add a 3rd column to *traffic_df* which is the associated **Alert.level** if the **Date_Time** falls within the **Start** and **End** Date_Time of the *Alert.level* df so that the resulting dataframe will look like this:

**Dataframe 1:** *traffic_df*

| Date_Time | Traffic | Alert.Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-09 06:00:00 | 10 |  |
| 2020-03-09 07:00:00 | 20 |  |
| 2020-03-10 07:00:00 | 20 | 2 |
| 2020-03-24 08:00:00 | 15 | 3 |

Is there anyway to do this without having to make a matching hourly dataframe and then using join?
I'm thinking somehow using the map function?

Code to produce the df:

```
traffic_df <- structure(list(Date_Time = c("2020-03-09 06:00:00", "2020-03-09 07:00:00", "2020-03-10 07:00:00", 
                              "2020-03-24 08:00:00"), Traffic = c(10L, 20L, 20L, 15L)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

Alert.Level = data.frame(Start = c("10/03/2020 13:30", "23/03/2020 13:30"), 
           End = c("23/03/2020 13:30", "25/03/2020 23:59"), 
           Alert.level = c(2, 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try the `fuzzyjoin` package.

**Data**

```
library(lubridate)

traffic_df <- structure(list(Date_Time = c("2020-03-09 06:00:00", "2020-03-09 07:00:00", "2020-03-10 07:00:00", 
                                           "2020-03-24 08:00:00"), Traffic = c(10L, 20L, 20L, 15L)), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame") %>%
  mutate(Date_Time = ymd_hms(Date_Time))

Alert.Level = data.frame(Start = c("10/03/2020 13:30", "23/03/2020 13:30"), 
                         End = c("23/03/2020 13:30", "25/03/2020 23:59"), 
                         Alert.level = c(2, 3)) %>% 
  mutate(Start = dmy_hms(Start),
         End = dmy_hms(End))
```

**Code**

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

traffic_df %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(Alert.Level,
                  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`),
                  by = list(x = c("Date_Time",
                                  "Date_Time"),
                            y = c("Start",
                                  "End"))) %>%
  select(-Start, -End)
```

**Output**
In contrast to your expected output above, row three is not matched, because 7:00 o'clock is before the starting time of 13:30.

```
            Date_Time Traffic Alert.level
1 2020-03-09 06:00:00      10          NA
2 2020-03-09 07:00:00      20          NA
3 2020-03-10 07:00:00      20          NA
4 2020-03-24 08:00:00      15           3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `sqldf`. Note that I renamed the data.frame to have an underscore for convenience with SQL.

```
library(sqldf)

Alert_level <- Alert.level

sqldf("SELECT * FROM traffic_df
       LEFT JOIN Alert_level
       ON traffic_df.Date_Time BETWEEN Alert_level.Start AND Alert_level.End")
```

**Output**

```
            Date_Time Traffic               Start                 End Alert.level
1 2020-03-09 06:00:00      10                <NA>                <NA>          NA
2 2020-03-09 07:00:00      20                <NA>                <NA>          NA
3 2020-03-10 07:00:00      20                <NA>                <NA>          NA
4 2020-03-24 08:00:00      15 2020-03-23 13:30:00 2020-03-25 23:59:00           3
```

Answer (score 1):

I like `outer` approaches in such cases. First, define a `Vectorize`d `FUN`ction, that looks if a specific `x` is between an `y` interval. Put it in `outer` which iterates each `Date_Time` with each start/end interval of `Alert.Level`. This gives a matrix `o` that informs `which` of the intervals is applicable (I use `unname` to avoid confusion). Then, in `traffic_df` we crate a `NA` column `alert_lv` (should just have a different name than "Alert.Level"), subset it with positive `colSums`, and put in the according levels of `Alert.Level`.

```
FUN <- Vectorize(function(x, y) x >= y[1] & x < y[2])
(o <- unname(outer(traffic_df$Date_Time, Alert.Level[-3], FUN)))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

w <- unlist(apply(o, 1, which))

traffic_df <- within(traffic_df, {
  alert_lv <- NA
  alert_lv[rowSums(o) > 0] <- Alert.Level[w, 3]
})
traffic_df
#             Date_Time Traffic alert_lv
# 1 2020-03-09 06:00:00      10       NA
# 2 2020-03-09 07:00:00      20       NA
# 3 2020-03-10 07:00:00      20        2
# 4 2020-03-24 08:00:00      15        3
```

**Note:** To use this solution you first need the usual 'POSIXct' formats, so first you should do

```
traffic_df$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(traffic_df$Date_Time)
Alert.Level[1:2] <- lapply(Alert.Level[1:2], strptime, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```